# Unable to consume oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: dataweave

I'm having issues when trying to transform response from Oracle Database, there is a column of datatype TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIMEZONE

Getting the error below: Invalid property name: `shareBytes` on class `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ`. Validate that the correct setters is present." evaluating expression:

Already tried passing the argument -Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true to the JVM but did not solve the issue as described in this link: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00005EM9T6SAL/how-to-read-the-value-from-oraclesqltimestamptz-field

I'm using Oracle JDBC Driver com.oracle.jdbc8:12.2.0.1 and mule runtime 4.3.0-20210119

Thanks

Comment: Please also share the DB operation -as XML text. Are you having that error in the DB connector operation or in a later operation? if in a later one please add that too.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the JVM argument to help anything, either.

I finally arrived at converting the `Timestamp with time zone` column to text on the server side, then casting it back to a `DateTime` in Dataweave.

```
-- SQL query
SELECT my_id
  to_char(my_date,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff4tzh:tzm') AS my_date
FROM my_table
ORDER BY my_date
```

For example, the DBMS is storing the value: `14.04.2022 20:27:05.419 +00:00`, and the conversion will output `2022-04-14T20:27:05.4198+00:00`

That specific output format for the column should allow you to cast it directly as a `DateTime` in DataWeave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map {
    "id": $.MY_ID,
    "date": $.MY_DATE as DateTime
}
```

And yields this output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1234567",
        "my_date": "2022-04-14T20:27:05.4198Z"
    }
]
```