# How to convert oracle.sql.timestamp into Java.sql.timestamp in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am fetching the data from Oracle database, it has a date column so when I try to map like this in dataweave

```
Payload map(object,index)->{
DOJ=payload.doj as Date
}
```

Now I m getting the below error
" Cannot coerce array to date"

I tried below code also
DOJ=payload.doj as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd} as DateTime

But still it is showing "cannot coerce array to string"

Comment: Please share the Java code. What JVM property is that you mentioned? No JVM configuration is likely to help with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried the method on https://stackoverflow.com/a/71913416/721855?

Comment: It may be that payload is an array so payload.doj is also an array. You may try with payload[0].doj . Also, why are you converting the date to string and then to date again?